# AzureAD - ConditionalAccessPolicy PersistentBrowser error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have the following script to create a Conditional Access policy but i get below error.
And i dont understand what is wrong

```
$conditions = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessConditionSet
$conditions.Applications = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessApplicationCondition
$conditions.Applications.IncludeApplications = "Office365"
$conditions.Users = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessUserCondition
$conditions.Users.IncludeRoles = @('62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10', 'f28a1f50-f6e7-4571-818b-6a12f2af6b6c', '29232cdf-9323-42fd-ade2-1d097af3e4de', 'b1be1c3e-b65d-4f19-8427-f6fa0d97feb9', '194ae4cb-b126-40b2-bd5b-6091b380977d', '729827e3-9c14-49f7-bb1b-9608f156bbb8', '966707d0-3269-4727-9be2-8c3a10f19b9d', 'b0f54661-2d74-4c50-afa3-1ec803f12efe', 'fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1')
$conditions.Users.ExcludeGroups = $ExcludeCAGroup.ObjectId
$conditions.ClientAppTypes = @('Browser', 'MobileAppsAndDesktopClients')
$controls = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessGrantControls
$controls._Operator = "OR"
$controls.BuiltInControls = "MFA"
$session = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.conditionalAccessSessionControls
$sessioncontrols = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessSignInFrequency
$sessioncontrols.Type = "days"
$sessioncontrols.Value = 30
$sessioncontrols.IsEnabled = $true
$session.SignInFrequency = $sessioncontrols

$persistent = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessPersistentBrowser
$persistent.IsEnabled = $true
$persistent.Mode = "never"
$session.PersistentBrowser = $persistent


New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy -DisplayName "GRANT: Require MFA for Admin users and never persistent sessions" -State "Disabled" -Conditions $conditions -GrantControls $controls -SessionControls $session
```

The error i get is

```
New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewAzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy 
Code: BadRequest
Message: 1032: ConditionalActionPolicy validation failed due to InvalidConditionsForPersistentBrowserSessionMode.
```

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have tried in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

- **If you are including persistent browser mode** in your script, then make sure to select **`All`** applications for session control as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/conditionalaccesssessioncontrols?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[image: Image2]

By Changing the `IncludeApplications` from office365 to **`All`** like below:

```php
$conditions.Applications.IncludeApplications = "All"
```

***I was able to create conditional access policy successfully*** :

[image: image3]

- I also tried keeping ***included app as office365***,but changed **`$persistent.IsEnabled=$false`** .This worked maybe because it can only be enabled for all apps as suggested in the MsDoc.

Comment: Thank you, i figured it out after reading the documentation again. But thanks for putting time into posting the solution!